# how to rearrange array by 2 arrays?

Tags: arrays, vb.net

There is some code I wrote. array a is the index of the c array and array b is the item of index a.

```
dim a={0,1,3}
dim b={5,1,1}
```

I want to create c array like this. The maximun array length is 5.

```
c={5,1,0,1,0}
```

Comment: what is the "specific condition"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to put the `i-th` element from `b` at the position specified by the `i-th` element from `a`, you can do as follows:

```
Dim c(a.Max()) As Integer
For i As Integer = 0 To a.GetUpperBound(0)
    c(a(i)) = b(i)
Next
'Result: c = { 5, 1, 0, 1 }
```

I am not sure how you came up with the maximum length of `5`. I just assumed that the array should be large enough to hold the maximum element in `a`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming array a and b are always equal in length and C has a length equal to the largest number in array b.

Keep in mind, that when you create array C that you have to subtract 1 from the max number.  C(5) will produce a 6 element array of `C(0), C(1), C(2), C(3), C(4), C(5)`

```
Imports System

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim A As Integer() = {0, 1, 3}
        Dim B As Integer() = {5, 1, 1}
        Dim C(B.Max() - 1) As Integer

        For Index = 0 To A.GetUpperBound(0)
            C(A(Index)) = B(Index)
        Next

        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", C))
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Result:

> 5 1 0 1 0